# Rails locally error (ruby 2.5.8), it works in the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localhost

I'm trying to run a rails app locally to make changes before pushing it to Heroku (where it's already running in production).

The app works fine when run in Heroku, but it's failing locally (rails s).

I have set up the environment variables as they are in Heroku.

Here is the execution:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.0 application starting in production 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
W, [2022-07-03T14:19:53.741206 #33004]  WARN -- : Creating scope :completed. Overwriting existing method Ticket.completed.
Exiting
```

This is the error trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        105: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
        104: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
        103: from /Users/diego/ror/railway-try/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
        102: from /Users/diego/ror/railway-try/bin/spring:15:in `require'
        101: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
        100: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
         99: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
         98: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
         97: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
         96: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
         95: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
         94: from /Users/diego/ror/railway-try/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
         93: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
         92: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
         91: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
         90: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
         89: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
         88: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
         87: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
         86: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
         85: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
         84: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
         83: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
         82: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
         81: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
         80: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
         79: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
         78: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
         77: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
         76: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:53:in `start'
         75: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:311:in `start'
         74: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:379:in `handle_profiling'
         73: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:312:in `block in start'
         72: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
         71: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:27:in `app'
         70: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
         69: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
         68: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
         67: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
         66: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
         65: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
         64: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
         63: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:44:in `require_relative'
         62: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
         61: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
         60: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
         59: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
         58: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
         57: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
         56: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
         55: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
         54: from /Users/diego/ror/railway-try/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
         53: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
         52: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
         51: from /Users/diego/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
         50: from /Users/diego/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
         49: from /Users/diego/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
         48: from /Users/diego/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
         47: from /Users/diego/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
         46: from /Users/diego/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
         45: from /Users/diego/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
         44: from /Users/diego/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
         43: from /Users/diego/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
         42: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
         41: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
         40: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
         39: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:130:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
         38: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:33:in `execute_if_updated'
         37: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:44:in `updater'
         36: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:83:in `execute'
         35: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:43:in `block in updater'
         34: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:19:in `reload!'
         33: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:50:in `clear!'
         32: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:50:in `each'
         31: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:52:in `block in clear!'
         30: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/actionpack-5.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:449:in `clear!'
         29: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/actionpack-5.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:449:in `each'
         28: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/actionpack-5.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:449:in `block in clear!'
         27: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/actionpack-5.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:432:in `eval_block'
         26: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/actionpack-5.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:432:in `instance_exec'
         25: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/actioncable-5.2.0/lib/action_cable/engine.rb:48:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Engine>'
         24: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/actioncable-5.2.0/lib/action_cable.rb:46:in `server'
         23: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
         22: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
         21: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
         20: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
         19: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
         18: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
         17: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
         16: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
         15: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/actioncable-5.2.0/lib/action_cable/server/base.rb:5:in `<main>'
         14: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/actioncable-5.2.0/lib/action_cable/server/base.rb:6:in `<module:ActionCable>'
         13: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/actioncable-5.2.0/lib/action_cable/server/base.rb:87:in `<module:Server>'
         12: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
         11: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
         10: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
          9: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:67:in `execute_hook'
          8: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:62:in `with_execution_control'
          7: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `block in execute_hook'
          6: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `instance_eval'
          5: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/actioncable-5.2.0/lib/action_cable/engine.rb:33:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
          4: from /Users/diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:235:in `config_for'
          3: from /Users/diego/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/lib/ruby/2.5.0/erb.rb:876:in `result'
          2: from /Users/diego/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/lib/ruby/2.5.0/erb.rb:876:in `eval'
          1: from (erb):3:in `<main>'
(erb):3:in `[]': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
```

I have tried to reinstall every gem and even ruby and rails, nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell after looking at the error trace, it seems like the error originates when action cable is trying to load the config file. You can try checking the `config/cable.yml` and see if you have the required environment variable present.